# jQuery is working on click of Cancel Button

Tags: php

I have one class that reference for stock function. and i have an file that contain php and jquery. In php code i check if product in stock is equal to zero, confirm box will pop up. The problem is that when i click on cancel button, ajax still run the function of the class and update my data in database but i observed that alert success did not load. how do i fix? sorry for my bad english.

**php file:**

```
<?php if($record['product_in_stock']<=0){?>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
                       <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                        if(confirm('Product in stock is empty now, Do you want to continue?')){
                                alert('ok');
                               var order_id="12059";


                              $.ajax({
                                    url:'components/com_virtuemart/classes/check_product_instock.php',
                                    type:'post',
                                    data: order_id,
                                    success: function(){
                                        alert(success);

                                    }
                                });

                            return true;
                          }else{
                                alert('no');
                               return false;
                          }

                         </script>
<?php }?>
```

**check_product_instock.php class**

```
    <?php
if( !defined( '_VALID_MOS' ) && !defined( '_JEXEC' ) ) die( 'Direct Access to '.basename(__FILE__).' is not allowed.' );
class checkStock{
    private $order_id;
function getOrderId(){
    if(isset($_POST['order_id'])){
        $this->order_id=$_POST['order_id'];

    }
}
function check(){

if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['order_id']>0){

$order_id=$_POST['order_id'];

        $q = "SELECT product_id, product_quantity FROM jos_vm_order_item WHERE order_id='".$order_id."'";

             $result=mysql_query($q);
              while ($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                  $q = "UPDATE jos_vm_product
                      SET product_in_stock=product_in_stock - ".$record["product_quantity"].",
                      product_sales=product_sales + ".$record["product_quantity"]."
                      WHERE product_id=".$record["product_id"];
                      mysql_query($q);

              }

        }
    }
}
$stock = new checkStock();
$stock->check();
```

Comment: Works fine **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/K6f7n/)**

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, I think you don't require **return true** and **return false** in the if condition.
- Secondly, You have to pass the parameter in the ajax function such as **data : 'order_id =' + order_id,**. Only then the php file(check_product_instock.php) can read the POST value.

Comment: thank for your answer. the problem is the confirm box is pop up and then i click on cancel button the script is still run the function in the class(check_product_in_stock)and update data in database. Lastly i also follow to your suggestion it still the same run the function in class.